# clonezilla:Failed to use partclone program to save or restore an image!

Tags: linux, clonezilla

When I was using the `clonezilla-live-20220502-jammy-amd64` version of clonezilla for a linux system backup, the following error occurred. When I executed the `e2fsck -f /dev/mmcblk0p2` command and backed up again, there was no error. I want to know the specific reason for it. I am concerned about any hidden system bugs that may cause exceptions when running programs on the backup system in the future.

```
Use partclone with pigz to save the image.
Image file will be split with size limit 4096 MB.

If this action fails or hangs, check:
* Is the disk full ?

Running: partclone.ext4 -2 10485760 -L /var/log/partclone.log -c -s /dev/sad2
Partclone y03.20 http://partclone.org
Starting to clone device (/dey/mmcblkOp2) to image (-)
Reading Super Block
Calculating bitmap.... Please wait ..1.00%extfsclone.c: bi
Elapsed: 00:00:01, Remaining: 00:01:39, Completed:1.00% 
Please run fsck to check and repair the file system
Partclone fail, please check /var/log/partclone.logChecking the disk space ..
Failed to use partclone program to save or restore an image!
```

Comment: It's telling you to run `fsck`, have you?

Comment: @Bib no, because after executing `e2fsck -f /dev/mmcblk0p2` in clonezilla live, if I go to backup again, there will be no errors, so I did not execute `fsck` again. Do I need to execute `fsck` in live?